# How to remove anchor tag text using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How to remove the anchor tag text and href link using `javascript` Or `Jquery`

```
<a id="ancID" href="Javascript:void(0)">Here insert a dynamic text </a>
```

I want to remove the text inserted between anchor tag..

Comment: using javascript regex can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.text('')` to remove text by assigning empty string. First use id selector to get the anchor tag.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cr3rD/)**

```
$('#ancID').text('');
```

Comment: if i want to remove <a tag and retrieve text between the <a tag then ?

Can you please provide solution using regex javascript

Answer (score 3):

If you go the vanilla way:

```
var x = document.getElementById("ancID");
x.innerHTML = "";
x.href = "";
```